# Ultimate CSS shortcut for specifying borders needed

Tags: css, shorthand

Needing help for some homework. I hope someone can help me out as I have tried all combinations with not much success. I've been asked to simplify the following:

```
border-top: 1px solid #8B8BA2; 
border-left: 1px solid #8B8BA2; 
border-bottom: 1px solid #8B8BA2;
```

Anyone have any great ideas. I did try the following but it didn't seem to work:

```
border: 1px solid none solid solid #8B8BA2;
```

Hope someone out there can help.

Mari

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Specifying the `border` attribute let's you specify all borders at once.  Since three out of four are the same, specify the border for all sides, and then remove the border for the one it doesn't apply to:

```
border: 1px solid #8B8BA2;
border-right: 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

As an addition to SeanA's answer (+1),  - if this is for homework you might be being asked if you actually know the shorthand border order.. so while the above works too, this might be the answer they're after.

```
border: 1px solid #8B8BA2;
border-width: 1px 0 1px 1px;
```

the first declares all borders, the second zero's the "right" border, using the four sided notation.. border (and margins and padding) are written `Top - Right - Bottom - Left` - **TRBL** and the word used to remember this is "**TR***ou***BL***e*" or you can just think clockwise :)

Comment: The other way is shorter though, so it immediately wins. ;)

Comment: wasn't concerned about winning, was just offering a homework solution. I **personally** find the four values easier to read than the words, but hey it's up to coder.. I did vote up "competing" answer, like I said it's not always about winning especially at homework stage ;)

Comment: I was just failing at trying to make a funny comment about how lazy programmers are. Hence the: ;)

Comment: hehe.. you didn't fail I did smile :) - I just wasn't sure, so please don't take my reply as a dig just put it down to "not enough coffee yet" - I get the "winning" now :)